# Writing a Permutation as a product of Disjoint Cycles

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

Write the following as a product of disjoint cycles:

$(1 3 2 5 6)(2 3)(4 6 5 1 2)$

I know from my solutions guide that the answer is:

$(1 2 4)(3 5)(6)$

but I don't know how to do that. I started by writing it as a product of transpositions as such:

$(1 3)(3 2)(2 5)(5 6)(2 3)(4 6)(6 5)(5 1)(1 2)$

I want to put this in standard form, but I don't know where to go from here...If anyone could help shed light on the procedure to do this, it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First write this product with one permutation and then into product of disjoint cycles:

$$(1 3  6)(1357) (1234)= \left(\begin{matrix}1&2&3&4&5&6\\
2&4&5&1&3&6\end{matrix}\right)=(1 2 4)(3 5).$$

Comment: My problem is that I don't understand the process to write it as one permutation. Why does 1 go to 2? Do you start from right to left? It's the intermediate step that I don't get..

Comment: I start from right to left: the image of $1$ by $(4 6 5 1 2)$ is $2$ and the image of $2$ by $(2 3)$ is $3$ and the image of $3$ by $(1 3 2 5 6)$ is $2$ so the image of $1$ by $(1 3 2 5 6)(2 3)(4 6 5 1 2)$ is $2$.

Comment: Thank you. This was the first answer that makes sense. I appreciate your help; I understand my homework problems a lot better now.

Answer (score 0):

For each number from 1 to 6, figure out where the permutation takes it, and continue this for each one until you build all the cycles.

For example, we follow 1's path to 2, to 3, to 2, so 1 goes to 2. Starting at 2 now, we see 2 goes to 4, and that's it. Finally, 4 goes to 6, then 1, so we have completed a cycle. Continue this until all cycles are found.

Comment: But looking at this beginning problem, it looks like 2 goes to 3 and 4. Which one is the one you choose? It also looks like 1 goes to 3 but it also goes to 2. It's the intermediate step that is confusing me.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with identity and having each composition map act as a row we get this:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
2 4 3 6 1 5
3 4 2 6 1 5
2 4 5 1 3 6
```

which means that it can be written directly by finding what takes us from the first to the last row as
(1 2 4) (3 5).